# Elasticsearch custom date time format incl. ordinal numbers

Tags: elasticsearch, datetime-format, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-date

I need to define the `format` for the `date` field in my index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "???"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to cover values like `February 10th 2021, 23:59:58.556`.

I tried `MMMM DD YYYY, HH:mm:ss.SSS` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the following:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "MMMM dd['st']['nd']['rd']['th'] yyyy', 'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`[]` denotes optional parts and `''` denotes literal parts. So the pattern says that the number of the day may be followed by `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th`.

The `', '` token is needed to cover the comma + whitespace separating the *date* from the *time*.

Answer (score 1):

look here: [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)

for example:

```
PUT 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_special_date_field": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

a list of all the built-in formats: [built-in formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

Comment: that not the correct format
`failed to parse date field [February 10th 2021 , 23:59:58.556] with format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]`

Comment: ah you mean you want the exact format that fits your input? check the 2nd link, i'll look through it as well.

Comment: Yes I need the format for `February 10th 2021 , 23:59:58.556` I didn't find an answer in your link

Comment: the closest thing i see is RFC_1123_DATE_TIME:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME
which the documentation says is supported.

Comment: But how can I write that in format of `mm-yyyy` ? I can't put `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` into format